# Check .apk-signature in C/native Code

Tags: android, c, signature, verification

I have developed an Android application which also contains a native part written in C (which does not depend on the app).

The application itself is useless if the shared library does not do its work.

I would like to let the native-part (a shared library) only do its work, if there exists an unmodified version of the application (.apk) it has been shipped with.

The best method for me would be this way:

1. Application get installed
2. Shared Library checks signature/hash of the application/.apk
3. Only does its work when the signature matches a known one

In this way, I would like to protect my application from modification and piracy.

Are there any tips for doing this? I just found posts with checking own signature in java, but that's jokeless if one could de- & recompile the app.

Comment: One could modify the shared library too.

Comment: Okay, I could try to prevent easy decompilation, I think decompiling C will be much harder than Java (I did this already by myself).

Comment: Oh, that's definitely true. It's not impossible, though.

Comment: Short answer: don't. If your objective is to fight piracy this will not succeed

Comment: Can you expand on why would that fail? Understandably there's no bullet-proof method, but at least preventing those automatic method from cracking apps would be nice. My apps are released 30 minutes after they are published on Play Store!

Comment: I use to add signature checks within the app and it prevented apps from being distributed cracked for a few months, but everything was in Java and within the app. Having a C library (or better a simple C binary) that the app can check its checksum, which then checks the app signature would definitely be a great help.

Comment: That's what I do meanwhile, checking the signature of the classes.dex within a JNI-library. But I calculated the signature and do not use the one which is provided by the JAVA-libraries. On each deployment, I am then creating the APK with DEBUG=1 which then prints me the new hash, then switch of DEBUG and compile the signature into the C-code. In my case bullet-proof, uncracked for 6 months meanwhile..

Comment: @Martin M., it will be great if you could provide some code.

Comment: > it will be great if you could provide some code -> done, hope it helps :)

Comment: @MartinL. Thanks a million for sharing your code. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I have been asked to publish some code how I'm now checking the CRC-code of my Java-application from within C, here are some snippets.

I cannot post a complete working solution as it's spread over multiple lines due to performance-reasons, but I hope this is most complete and working:

In your MyApplication.java:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static Context context;

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -DDEBUG_MODE=0 -DCLASSES_CRC=2331492378
```

Inside your C-code:

```
#define LOG_TAG "Your Log Tag"

#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

#if DEBUG_MODE
#define LOGDH(...) LOGD(__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGIH(...) LOGI(__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGEH(...) LOGE(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOGDH(...) //
#define LOGIH(...) //
#define LOGEH(...) //
#endif

int isSecure = -1;

jclass MyApplication;
jclass Context;
jclass ApplicationInfo;


jclass ZipFile;
jclass ZipEntry;
jclass CheckedInputStream;
jclass Adler32;
jclass Checksum;

jmethodID MyApplication_getAppContextMethodId;
jmethodID Context_getApplicationInfoMethodId;

jmethodID ZipFile_ConstructorMethodId;
jmethodID CheckedInputStream_ConstructorMethodId;
jmethodID Adler32_ConstructorMethodId;

jmethodID ZipFile_getEntryMethodId;
jmethodID ZipFile_getInputStreamMethodId;
jmethodID CheckedInputStream_readMethodId;
jmethodID CheckedInputStream_getChecksumMethodId;
jmethodID Checksum_getValueMethodId;

jfieldID ApplicationInfo_flagsFieldId;
jfieldID ApplicationInfo_FLAG_DEBUGGABLEFieldId;
jfieldID ApplicationInfo_sourceDirFieldId;


static long getClassesCRC(JNIEnv *env) {
    jobject appContextInstance = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,
            MyApplication, MyApplication_getAppContextMethodId);
    if (!appContextInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of AppContext");
        return false;
    }

    jobject applicationInfoInstance = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,
            appContextInstance, Context_getApplicationInfoMethodId);
    if (!appContextInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of ApplicationInfo");
        return false;
    }

    jobject zipFileInstance = (*env)->NewObject(env, ZipFile,
            ZipFile_ConstructorMethodId,
            (*env)->GetObjectField(env, applicationInfoInstance,
                    ApplicationInfo_sourceDirFieldId));
    if (!zipFileInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of ZipFile");
        return -1;
    }

    jstring classesDexString = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "classes.dex");
    jobject zipEntryInstance = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, zipFileInstance,
            ZipFile_getEntryMethodId, classesDexString);
    if (!zipFileInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of ZipEntry");
        return -1;
    }
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, classesDexString);

    jobject adler32Instance = (*env)->NewObject(env, Adler32,
            Adler32_ConstructorMethodId);
    if (!adler32Instance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of Adler32");
        return -1;
    }

    jobject inputStreamInstance = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, zipFileInstance,
            ZipFile_getInputStreamMethodId, zipEntryInstance);
    if (!inputStreamInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of InputStream");
        return -1;
    }

    jobject checkedInputStreamInstance = (*env)->NewObject(env,
            CheckedInputStream, CheckedInputStream_ConstructorMethodId,
            inputStreamInstance, adler32Instance);
    if (!checkedInputStreamInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of CheckedInputStream");
        return -1;
    }

    int bufferSize = 128;
    jbyteArray bufferBytes = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, bufferSize);

    while ((*env)->CallIntMethod(env, checkedInputStreamInstance,
            CheckedInputStream_readMethodId, bufferBytes) > 0) {
    }
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, bufferBytes);

    jobject checksumInstance = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,
            checkedInputStreamInstance, CheckedInputStream_getChecksumMethodId);
    if (!checksumInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of CheckSum");
        return -1;
    }

    return (*env)->CallLongMethod(env, checksumInstance,
            Checksum_getValueMethodId);
}

static bool isDebuggable(JNIEnv *env) {
    jobject appContextInstance = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,
            MyApplication, Application_getAppContextMethodId);
    if (!appContextInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of AppContext");
        return false;
    }

    jobject applicationInfoInstance = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,
            appContextInstance, Context_getApplicationInfoMethodId);
    if (!appContextInstance) {
        LOGEH("Unable to get instance of ApplicationInfo");
        return false;
    }

    int FLAG_DEBUGGABLE = (*env)->GetStaticIntField(env, ApplicationInfo,
            ApplicationInfo_FLAG_DEBUGGABLEFieldId);
    int flags = (*env)->GetIntField(env, applicationInfoInstance,
            ApplicationInfo_flagsFieldId);

    return (0 != (flags &= FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
}

static bool isSecureEnvironment(JNIEnv *env) {

    //isSecure = true; // TODO remove this

    if (isSecure == -1) {
        isSecure = true;

        if (isDebuggable(env)) {
            // someone used the app in debug-mode
#if DEBUG_MODE != 1
            // TODO report

#endif
            LOGEH("App IS DEBUGGABLE!");
            isSecure = false;
        } else {

            // check CRC
            long classesCRC = getClassesCRC(env);
            if (classesCRC != (long) CLASSES_CRC) {
#if DEBUG_MODE != 1
                // TODO report
#endif
                LOGEH("CRC-CHECK FAILED: %lu", classesCRC);

                isSecure = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isSecure;
}


static bool initJavaClasses(JNIEnv * env) {
    jclass local = (*env)->FindClass(env, "eu/my/MyApplication");
    MyApplication = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local);
    if (!MyApplication) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the MyApplication class");
    return false;
    }
    local = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/Context");
    Context = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, local);
    if (!Context) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the Context class");
    return false;
    }
    local = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo");
    ApplicationInfo = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, local);
    if (!ApplicationInfo) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the ApplicationInfo class");
    return false;
    }

    local = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/zip/ZipFile");
    ZipFile = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, local);
    if (!ZipFile) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the ZipFile class");
    return false;
    }

    local = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/zip/ZipEntry");
    ZipEntry = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, local);
    if (!ZipEntry) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the ZipEntry class");
    return false;
    }

    local = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/zip/CheckedInputStream");
    CheckedInputStream = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, local);
    if (!CheckedInputStream) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the CheckedInputStream class");
    return false;
    }

    local = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/zip/Adler32");
    Adler32 = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, local);
    if (!Adler32) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the Adler32 class");
    return false;
    }

    local = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/zip/Checksum");
    Checksum = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, local);
    if (!Checksum) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the Checksum class");
    return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool initJavaMethods(JNIEnv * env) {
    MyApplication_getAppContextMethodId = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,
    MyApplication, "getAppContext", "()Landroid/content/Context;");
    if (!MyApplication_getAppContextMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the getAppContext method");
    return false;
    }
    Context_getApplicationInfoMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, Context,
    "getApplicationInfo", "()Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;");
    if (!Context_getApplicationInfoMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the getApplicationInfo method");
    return false;
    }

    ZipFile_ConstructorMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ZipFile, "<init>",
    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (!ZipFile_ConstructorMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the constructor method");
    return false;
    }

    CheckedInputStream_ConstructorMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,
    CheckedInputStream, "<init>",
    "(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/zip/Checksum;)V");
    if (!CheckedInputStream_ConstructorMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the constructor method");
    return false;
    }

    Adler32_ConstructorMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, Adler32, "<init>",
    "()V");
    if (!Adler32_ConstructorMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the constructor method");
    return false;
    }

    ZipFile_getEntryMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ZipFile, "getEntry",
    "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;");
    if (!ZipFile_getEntryMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the getEntry method");
    return false;
    }

    ZipFile_getInputStreamMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ZipFile,
    "getInputStream", "(Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;)Ljava/io/InputStream;");
    if (!ZipFile_getInputStreamMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the getInputStream method");
    return false;
    }

    CheckedInputStream_readMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, CheckedInputStream,
    "read", "([B)I");
    if (!CheckedInputStream_readMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the read method");
    return false;
    }

    CheckedInputStream_getChecksumMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,
    CheckedInputStream, "getChecksum", "()Ljava/util/zip/Checksum;");
    if (!CheckedInputStream_getChecksumMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the getChecksum method");
    return false;
    }

    Checksum_getValueMethodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, Checksum, "getValue",
    "()J");
    if (!Checksum_getValueMethodId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the getValue method");
    return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool initJavaFields(JNIEnv * env) {
    ApplicationInfo_flagsFieldId = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, ApplicationInfo, "flags",
    "I");

    if (!ApplicationInfo_flagsFieldId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to find the flags field");
    return false;
    }

    ApplicationInfo_FLAG_DEBUGGABLEFieldId = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,
    ApplicationInfo, "FLAG_DEBUGGABLE", "I");
    if (!ApplicationInfo_FLAG_DEBUGGABLEFieldId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to get static field FLAG_DEBUGGABLE");
    return false;
    }

    ApplicationInfo_sourceDirFieldId = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, ApplicationInfo,
    "sourceDir", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (!ApplicationInfo_sourceDirFieldId) {
    LOGEH("Unable to get static field sourceDir");
    return false;
    }

    return true;
}


jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    (void) reserved; // Suppress the warning.
    JNIEnv * env;

    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
    return -1;
    }

    if (!initJavaClasses(env)) {
    return -1;
    }

    if (!initJavaMethods(env)) {
    return -1;
    }

    if (!initJavaFields(env)) {
    return -1;
    }

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Don't forget to add the methods of the MyApplication into the Proguard-settings to prevent their remove!

Usage:

1. Create your APK with -DDEBUG_MODE=1
2. start the APK on your Android
3. read the value inside "CRC-check failed:xxx"
4. take that value and insert it into CLASSES_CRC=xxxx
5. switch to -DDEBUG_MODE=0
6. rebuild your APK
7. check if your app is running well
8. publish

This method is a little more complicated as it requires 2 builds to get a valid APK.
But as the CRC is checked inside C and not just the dummy-signature of the APK-file is taken, this check is nearly bullet-proof.

In my situation, I'm for exampling not even doing the setup of the license-mechanisms in case the signature is invalid.

Additionally, as this method only uses numbers and not chars, it's fully compiled.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This was secure only in the sense of being unusual and so requiring specific attention if it remained unique - all of those invocations of jni methods by name at runtime are a ready place for subversion.

Comment: Sure, you can never get around this.. more it's a better way to do it in C than in Java, in my opinion ;)

Comment: You are still, for all practical purposes, doing the critical parts of it in Java, but invoked in a way that is actually more subvertable, not less.

Comment: You are right, I should re-check the web how to perform CRC-checks within pure C on Android.

Comment: this is to slow for my project. My project is about 7 mb and CRC check takes about 7 seconds. do you have any idea to improve this time.

Comment: It takes 850 ms over a 4mb apk so it's an acceptable time for me

Comment: However, starting from the above sample, you can get apk signature (I mean through getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(...)). That's what's I did and works flawlessly.

Comment: the check duration is not acceptable for me. Do you have any performance improvement solution?

Comment: @fillobotto this links is related signature check not crc check

Comment: @cahitbeyaz it works, it's secure and it's fast. What's the problem with it?

Comment: besides signature i also need whole binary checks like @MartinL. answered  above

Comment: @MartinL. `isSecureEnvironment` is never called , from where to call that method?