# Replacing .so file in signed apk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have generated signed apk from Android Studio, it contains ndk and compiled as .so in lib folder inside the apk.

Because of a problem I am facing here: 
[Checksum value of classes.dex keep changing with Dexguard for every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424581/checksum-value-of-classes-dex-keep-changing-with-dexguard-for-every-build)

I want to replace the .so without re-building the classes.dex in the signed apk. However, after unzipping the apk and re-pack it. It cannot be installed, although I have signed the re-packed apk again using "jarsigner -verbose -keystore".

Any hints for how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run zipalign after signing?

```
zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-signed.apk your_project_name-aligned.apk
```

See the final step in http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually